# Using preventDefault but jQuery ajax POST Still Returns Canceled

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

why is my post is being cancelled in the network tab of chrome when i enter some data into the textbox and click sign up? I've even put in preventDefault() but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<input autofocus style="width: 200pt" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" />
<input type="submit" value="Sign up" id="submit" class="button green" />        

    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/welcome/register",
            data:  {email: email},
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.success === true) {
                    alert('You have successfully registered.');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I always intercept the .submit() on the form element instead of the click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the type=submit from the input. I would replace it with type="button". Well if it's a button that is.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I needed to add 'www' to my base_url() because my web host adds 'www' to my domain whenever someone accesses the site without the 'www'

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. I needed to add 'www' to my base_url() because my web host adds 'www' to my domain whenever someone accesses the site without the 'www'